# Capturing of keydown events in a html page with frames

Tags: javascript, html, keydown

I have a jsp page with frames

```
<%@ include file="/includes/taglibs.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Welcome</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(this).keydown(function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode==27){
                    alert("escape pressed");
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
          });       
        }   
        );  
      </script> 
  </head>
      <frameset rows="42,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" id="framest">
          <frame src="/xyz/abc.html" scrolling="no" name="frame1"/>
          <frame src="/xyz/init.html" scrolling="no" name="frame2"/>
      </frameset>
</html>
```

I am trying to capture escape key press. But this doesn't seem to work. On each individual frame html if I write the same code of capturing , it works perfectly fine.

What changes should I make in the code above so that I would write the keydown code just once which enables me to capture keydown on anywhere on page on any frame.

Comment: Bit unrelated, but `frames` are kind of deprecated now, I strongly suggest using `iframes` instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember a frame is a completely new HTML page with a whole separate DOM, so jQuery doesn't include it in your bindings.

So you will need to bind to those documents also:

```
function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==27){
        alert("escape pressed");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

for (var id in window.parent.frames)
    $(window.parent.frames[id].document).keydown(keyDownHandler);
$(document).keydown(keyDownHandler);
```

#### If the above doesn't work for you because of the `id`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < window.parent.frames.length; i ++) {
   var frame = window.parent.frames[i].document;
   frame.addEventListener("keydown",keyDownHandler, true);
}
```

#### If you want to reference all frames, from the top level

```
for (var i = 0; i < top.window.frames.length; i ++) {
   var frame = top.window.frames[i].document;
   frame.addEventListener("keydown",keyDownHandler, true);
}
```

Comment: what if my iframes don't have IDs ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

Write your code in .js file and include file in all frames. This way you have to write function only onces and you can call it in all frames.

Hope this hepls.