# JavaScript keyDown Does Not Fire

Tags: javascript

I have a page in a modal window where I am displaying a slide show. The intended audience is for tablet users and they navigate the show by swiping from the right to the left or the left to the right to see the next or previous slide. This all works beautifully.

However, in the event that someone does view the page using a computer, I would like them to be able to navigate using the arrow keys on their keyboard. I'm able to detect the keystroke, but only after the user has clicked inside the modal window. I would really like the user to not have to click anywhere before the keyboard navigation shows up. It doesn't seem to matter what I try, this is always the problem.

Please note, because this is a modal window, it brings its contents in through the use of an iFrame.

Here is the code. I have confirmed that it does run when the page loads, and the pageTurn function works with other events:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){   
    if (e == null) {
        keycode = event.keyCode;
    } else {
        keycode = e.which;
    }
    if(keycode == 37){
        pageTurn('right');
    } else if(keycode == 39){
        pageTurn('left');
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try attaching the event to `document.documentElement` instead of just `document`.

If this fails, try adding `document.body.focus()` to ensure the document is ready to receive keyboard input.

EDIT: Inside an iFrame, the event needs to be attached to the `top.document.documentElement` instead, or attached to all frames as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613213/capturing-of-keydown-events-in-a-html-page-with-frames/4613271#4613271)

Comment: Neither of these did anything different. Perhaps, because it is a modal window with iFramed content I should be accessing the parent object somehow? I'm not sure. I tried parent.focus() but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Ah, if it's an iframe then it's a bit more complicated. You need to attach the event to `top.document.documentElement` instead.

Comment: Yes!! That did the trick. I am marking this answer as correct. Please update your answer to include the iFrame scenario. Thank you very much!

Comment: `document` is fine, no need for `documentElement`.

Comment: Thanks the body focus worked for me.We had a similar issue with 2 yui rich text editors in same page where keydown in second editor was nor fired.After body focus in click event handler of second editor , keydown started working thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`document` is fine for attaching key events. Also, `keyCode` is the correct property in all major browsers for `keydown` and `keyup` events, so there's no need to mess around with `which`.

For attaching to the parent document from within an iframe, as one of your comments suggests, you need to use `parent` (for the immediate parent document's window) or `top` (the outermost document's window):

```
parent.document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || parent.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 37) {
        pageTurn('right');
    } else if (keyCode == 39) {
        pageTurn('left');
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your key codes are wrong. Here is a page which shows you the codes for your browser: http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

If the codes are correct, compare the event handling code on this page with your version.

Comment: Well, I knew the key codes were right, as they worked once I clicked inside the screen. The thing I find interesting about the event handling in the example you set is that it begins by setting the focus to a text box. As I said, clicking on the screen does get my code to work, so the issue does seem to be focus somehow, but I don't have a text box I want the user to type in, I want to use the arrows for navigation. I have tried bringing focus to elements in the page (div ids, hidden input fields, etc) but none of these seems to work in my circumstance.