# Best way of attaching event listener to the whole html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mouseevent

Let's consider the problem of capturing `mousemove` on the whole HTML document.

I know four objects to which event listener can be attached:

`window`, `document`, `document.body`, `document.documentElement`

After simple tests it seemed to me that attaching to any of them has the same effect.

```
$(window).on('mousemove', function(){console.log(1)})
```

I was wondering if there is any difference I don't know about (performance, compatibility?)

Comment: As far as I know both `window` and `document.documentElement` attach to `html` whereas `document.body` attaches to `body` which isn’t guaranteed to cover the whole page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two potential issuses with binding the event to the `document.body` object:

- Some browsers doesn't allow accessing the body object before the content in the page has begun being parsed, so binding the event directly in the head won't work. You need to bind it from the `load` or `ready` event, or from code inside the body.
- In standards compliant mode (HTML 4, XHTML, HTML5) the body element doesn't automatically cover the entire window. It will only be as large as it needs to contain the content, and if it has a margin that is not covered by the body element.

Also, if the page contains frames, then this won't work. In that case, follow steps explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613213/capturing-of-keydown-events-in-a-html-page-with-frames/4613271#4613271).